# how to make user enter the path of the xml file in tinyxml2

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

How i can make the user enter the path of the xml file to be saved?

I want the user to enter something like "c:\test.xml"
and the xml file is generated by that name and location.

I tried

```
 string PathName;
 cin >> PathName;
XMLDocument doc;
doc.SaveFile(PathName);
```

but it gives me the error

```
 no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list
```

I know its such a simple question but somehow I am stuck, sorry

Comment: Why not read the project's documentation to find out how to use it?

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings, I want to create a new xml file based on the inserted path name

Comment: That doesn't explain why you're not using the project's documentation.

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings, its a personal project lol

Comment: @Asteroids With Wings, if I know how to use it I would not ask? I have been following it correctly but got stuck at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your error is telling the parameter type doesn't match an overload. Try this instead:

```
auto result = doc.SaveFile(PathName.c_str());
```

Edited to include result from the function - if it fails it should give you an error code. Quoting the docs:

> Save the XML file to disk. Returns XML_SUCCESS (0) on success, or an errorID.

Comment: now the program works but it does not save the file by the inserted name and path

Comment: You need to provide more information then. What is the filename/path you are passing in? How are you running the program?

Comment: I want the user to enter the path to where the file should locate and the name for it. For example the input is "c:\test.xml" the program saves the file in c with the name test. I am using VS2019

Comment: If you are trying to save to the C drive (as opposed to a user directory) make sure you are running VS with admin privileges

Comment: I am running it with admin privileges, also I am trying to save it to anywhere really, it depends on the user

Comment: Try checking the return from the function - edited my answer with more info.

Comment: Btw I have just tried this myself and it works. If there is more to your code, please share it. Also consider hard-coding your filename to remove the possibility of user input error.